# How to call hook in class component in React Native?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, themes

***Tech used***

React Native Appearance, Typescript & Redux Rematch.

***Problem***

I am attempting to pass my customized theme colours into a class component. I also understand that hooks cannot be used/called within a class component and only a functional component. The reason why I am using a class component is because of Redux Rematch. Is there a way for me to get my colours from the hook listed below into my class component?

This is how I am building my theme:

**index.tsx**

```
const palette = {
 colourTextDark: "#ffffff",
 colourTextLight: "#000000",
};

export const colors = {
  colourText: palette.colourTextLight,
};

export const themedColors = {
  default: {
    ...colors,
  },
  light: {
    ...colors,
  },
  dark: {
    ...colors,
    colourText: palette.colourTextDark,
  },
};
```

**hooks.tsx**

```
import { useColorScheme } from "react-native-appearance";
import { themedColors } from "./";

export const useTheme = () => {
  const theme = useColorScheme();
  const colors = theme ? themedColors[theme] : themedColors.default;
  return {
    colors,
    theme,
  };
};
```

Ideally I would want to use it like so:

```
import { useTheme } from "../../theme/hooks";

...

class Example extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
     // This doesn't work
     const { colors } = useTheme();

     return (
        <Text style={{ color: colors.colourText }}>Please help :)</Text>
     )
  }
}
```

How would I be able to do this? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a high order component like this:

```
const themeHOC = (Component) => {
  return (WrappedComponent = (props) => {
    const { colors } = useTheme();

    return <Component {...props} colors={colors} />;
  });
};
```

And use it like this:

```
themeHOC(<Example />)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
componentDidMount() {
    (async () => {
        const theme = useColorScheme() === "dark" ? styles.dark : styles.light;
        this.setState({ theme });
    })();
    this.sendEmail();
}
```